# How to find parent div and then change attribute of a children within the parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a some divs (parents) with the `class="block"` and within this div there is a link button to change the src of an image. My problem is that i have have more than 10 blocks with the `class="block"` and the change needs to be applied only to the parent and not to all classes.

Heres an example with 3 times the same HTML blocks. I need to change the Url but not of every block and i dont want to give each block a diferrent ID or class.

```
<div class="block>
  <div>
    <img src="someURL" class="image" alt=""/>
  </div>

  <div class="buttonlink">
    <a class="btn" id="change" href="#" onClick="changeImage(); return false">change</a>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="block>
  <div>
    <img src="someURL" class="image" alt=""/>
  </div>

  <div class="buttonlink">
    <a class="btn" id="change" href="#" onClick="changeImage(); return false">change</a>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="block>
  <div>
    <img src="someURL" class="image" alt=""/>
  </div>

  <div class="buttonlink">
    <a class="btn" id="change" href="#" onClick="changeImage(); return false">change</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Javascript/Jquery

```
function changeImage() {

        $('.image').attr("src","../img/checkgrau.png");

}
```

Comment: Doesn't the .closest work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `onclick` and since you are using jquery, try this

```
$( ".block .buttonlink .btn" ).click( function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //to prevent default action on anchor click
  $( this ).closest( ".block" ).find( "img" ).attr( "src", "../img/checkgrau.png" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In changeImage() pass "this" like :

```
onClick="changeImage(this); return false"
```

Then in the function do:

```
function changeImage(element) {
    $(element).closest('.block').find('.image').attr("src","../img/checkgrau.png");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used below jquery code for your problem not used function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        $(this).parent(".buttonlink").parent(".block").children("div").children("img").attr("src","YOUR_IMAGE_URL");
    });
});
```

please check this if you required more